Are the accelerated charges the real reason for the magnetic induction?
I have watched an explanatory video from YouTube that stated that the real reason for the "magnetic induction" are electric field lines of an accelerated charge, that have a component in the direction of the acceleration. As magnetic field is always present when a charge moves, and as the accelerated charge obviously moves non uniformly, the magnetic field will be varying. So the varying magnetic field is associeted with induction, but is not the cause of it. Unfortunately I can't find the link of the video to share with you.

My question is: are you agree with this? 
And if you are, is it ok to say that this is also the reason for self induction of an accelerated charge?

No, I don't agree. More specifically, you can get a varying magnetic field by changing the position of your 'induced' coil relative to a static magnetic field.

@JonCuster Remember the Richard Feynman's statement about the magnetic field, that there is no such thing, roughly speaking. I posted a separated question about that topic, you can check it out here.
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/813661/magnetic-field-as-a-relativistic-effect-by-richard-feynman

Yes, this explanation works in cases where the EMF is due to electric current in a stationary circuit changing in time. Magnetic flux is proportional to current, so according to the Faraday law, induced emf is proportional to rate of change of electric current, that is, to magnitude of acceleration of the charged particles that make up the current. This includes self-induction of any current distribution.
In other cases of EMF, such as when the EMF is due to motion of constant source of magnetic field (e.g. a magnet), this explanation does not seem to work, because the EMF is proportional to magnet velocity, and it is hard to see how it is proportional to acceleration of charged particles in the system.

Let's say that you have a hypothetical charged particle. You are exerting a force to accelerate it, the particle resists the acceleration. Conversely when it moves with a constant speed and you are exerting a force to decelerate it, it resists the deceleration. This happens is due to the self induction. But this behavior mimics the inertial mass concept. Suppose that you only can measure its mass by accelerating it, suppose you have no gravity to weight it. How can you tell its mass? Moreover, if your hypothetical particle were massless, how could you tell that?

@question-asker Yes, self-induction increases inertial mass (in case of mobile charges in inductor, it can be by many orders of magnitude). Measuring motion under known external force will allow us to determine only effective inertial mass, affected by the self-induction effect. Based on the Eotvos and later experiments, we believe measuring gravity mass will give the same result. Measuring the bare mass is not possible.

Another question. Imagine you have a charged particle. You are accelerating the particle, and you are getting the self induction effect as the expected result. Now imagine you put the same particle inside of a uniformly charged dielectric shell. The charge of the shell is opposite to that of the particle, but not necessarily equal. So the electric field that goes form the particle to the shell is stronger. Now you accelerate the particle inside the shell. The question is: Will the self-induction be greater, due to the stronger E field?

@question-asker self-induction is just due to action of the charged particle parts on themselves (via their EM fields). The charged shell around the particle does not belong to that set of interactions, it can only add another induction effects on the particle. This happens if the charges in the shell move. If the shell is heavy enough, they don't move, and there is no effect on the motion of the particle.
